# CSS Horizontal Menu using floats and display inline giving containing element a height

Tags: html, css

HTML for both examples:

```
<div id="nav">
    <ul>
        <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Services</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">About Us</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Contact Us</a></li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

CSS with `display: inline` only:

```
ul {
    background-color: cyan;
    padding-left: 0;
    margin-left: 0;
    float: left;
    width: 100%;
}

ul li {
    display: inline;
}

ul li a {
    padding: 0.2em 1em;
    background-color: #036;
    color: white;
    text-decoration: none;
    border-right: 1px solid white;
}
```

Result:

https://jsfiddle.net/cbaanvzd/

CSS with `float: left` and `display: inline`

```
ul {
    background-color: cyan;
    padding-left: 0;
    margin-left: 0;
    float: left;
    width: 100%;
}

ul li {
    display: inline;
}

ul li a {
    padding: 0.2em 1em;
    background-color: #036;
    color: white;
    text-decoration: none;
    border-right: 1px solid white;
    float: left;
}
```

Result:

https://jsfiddle.net/dy78hzk5/

Why does floating the element in the second example adjust the height of the containing element? There is now overflow property or clearfix being applied here.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure why, however if you would like to prevent this you can remove `float: left;` from the css for `ul li a` and place it in the css for `ul li`.

JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/dy78hzk5/1/

Answer (score 0):

It is a bit unclear what you are trying to achieve, but from what i understood, this is what you want? (check fiddle)

https://jsfiddle.net/3626pqcw/

CSS

```
ul {
    background-color: cyan;
    padding-left: 0;
    margin-left: 0;
    float: left;
    width: 100%;
}

ul li {
    display: inline;
    float: left;
}

ul li a {
    padding: 0.2em 1em;
    background-color: #036;
    color: white;
    text-decoration: none;
    border-right: 1px solid white;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It is the padding top and bottom of `a` that is overflowing the parent of `li`, to solve this problem just add the same padding to the `ul`(the parent of `li`).

```css
ul {
 background-color: cyan;
 padding-left: 0;
 margin-left: 0;
 float: left;
 width: 100%;
        padding: 0.2em 0; /* Padding top and bottom that I have added */
}

ul li {
 display: inline;
}

ul li a {
 padding: 0.2em 1em;
 background-color: #036;
 color: white;
 text-decoration: none;
 border-right: 1px solid white;
}
```

```html
 <div id="nav">
  <ul>
   <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
   <li><a href="#">Services</a></li>
   <li><a href="#">About Us</a></li>
   <li><a href="#">Contact Us</a></li>
  </ul>
 </div>
```